# Checking Given Number in From and To column in a table mysql

Tags: mysql

Just I want to share you something.

Today I tried to search a given no. in ranges from and to columns. Here is a example table.

```
+----+---------+------------+----------+
| id | book_no | from_range | to_range |
+----+---------------------------------+
|  2 |  1234   |      52800 |  52900   |
|  3 |  1230   |       1000 |  2000    |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
```

Assume I have no. 52900. I need book no. if the given no. in from and to ranges column.

```
select book_no from book_ranges where 52900 >= from_range AND 52900 <= to_range ;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Answer:

MariaDB [dbbms]> select book_no from book_ranges where  52900 >= from_range AND 52900 <= to_range  ;
+---------+
| book_no |
+---------+
| 1234    |
+---------+

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `AND` operator like this,

```
SELECT book_no from book_table_name WHERE from_range>=52900 AND to_range<=52900
```

Make sure this might return result-set of multiple rows. Assuming from and to both fields inclusive of the number.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `between` operator for this:

```
select book_no 
from   book_table_name 
where  52900 between from_range and to_range
```